# Operator norm of X

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I've been trying to prove that the operator norm of $\hat{X}\phi(x) = x\phi(x)$ with $\phi(x) \in L^2[0,1]$ is given by:
$$
||\hat{X}|| = \sup_{||\phi(x)||=1} ||\hat{X}\phi(x)||=1
$$
However i havent been able to do it. I asked my professor for help and he suggested that i consider a series of functions $\phi_n(x)$ of unit norm with support on$[a_n,1]$ with  $a_n \in (0,1)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=1$. Honestly that left me even more confused. Everywhere i searched seems to give this almost as a defnition.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0 \leq a < 1$ and suppose $\phi \in L^2[0,1]$ is supported on some subset of $[a,1]$. Then
$$\int_a^1a^2 \phi(x)^2 \,dx \leq \int_a^1 x^2\phi(x)^2\,dx \leq \int_a^1 1^2\phi(x)^2\,dx$$
which, since $\phi(x) = 0$ for $0 \leq x < a$, is equivalent to
$$a^2\int_0^1\phi(x)^2\,dx \leq \int_0^1(\hat{X}\phi)(x)^2\,dx \leq \int_0^1\phi(x)^2\,dx$$
and by taking square roots,
$$a\|\phi\| \leq \|\hat{X}\phi\| \leq \|\phi\|.$$

---

Now, any $\phi \in L^2[0,1]$ is supported on some subset of $[0,1]$, so by setting $a=0$, we have that $\|\hat{X}\phi\| \leq \|\phi\|$ for any $\phi \in L^2[0,1]$, and therefore $\|\hat{X}\| \leq 1$.

On the other hand, given any $0\leq a < 1$, there will be some nonzero $\phi \in L^2[0,1]$ which is supported on $[a,1]$, so $$\|\hat{X}\| \geq \frac{\|\hat{X}\phi\|}{\|\phi\|} \geq a$$ and by letting $a\to 1^-$, we have $\|\hat{X}\| \geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think i understand pretty much everything up to your last equation, this might be a dumb question but is it obvious that $||\hat{X}|| \geq \frac{||\hat{X}\phi||}{||\phi||}$?

Comment: It's not a dumb question (especially since I've used one of the equivalent definitions of operator norm).  Specifically, $$\frac{\|\hat{X}\phi\|}{\|\phi\|} = \left\|\hat{X}\left(\frac{\phi}{\|\phi\|}\right)\right\| \leq \sup_{\|\psi\|=1}\|\hat{X}\psi\| = \|\hat{X}\|$$ because $\psi = \frac{\phi}{\|\phi\|}$ has norm $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi_{n}(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-a_{n}}}\chi_{[a_{n},1]}$, then $\|\phi_{n}\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}=1$ and
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}(x\phi_{n}(x))^{2}dx=\dfrac{1}{1-a_{n}}\int_{a_{n}}^{1}x^{2}dx=\dfrac{1}{1-a_{n}}\dfrac{1}{3}(1-a_{n})(1+a_{n}+a_{n}^{2})=\dfrac{1+a_{n}+a_{n}^{2}}{3},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|x\phi_{n}(x)\|_{L^{2}[0,1]}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+a_{n}+a_{n}^{2}}{3}}\rightarrow 1. 
\end{align*}